# Python: Using FFMPEG to create a video using a series of images

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am fairly new to Python and this is my first time using ffmpeg (basing this code on a colleagues).

I have some code that takes a snapshot of the screen every X seconds and then creates a video out of these files however I am having issues when creating the video. This is my code for generating the video:

```
def create_video(screen_resolution, image_location, subfolder, count, preset, qaulity, duplicated_frame, video_path, video_filename):
video_path = path + video_path
    {1}\\%d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -preset {2} -crf {3} -r {4} -pix_fmt yuv420p {5}\\{6}.mp4"
proc = subprocess.Popen("C:\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe -r 1 -f image2 -s %s \
                            -pattern_type sequence \
                            -start_number 1 \
                            -i %s%s\\%s%d.png \
                            -vcodec libx264 \
                            -preset %s \
                            -crf %s \
                            -r %s \
                            -pix_fmt yuv420p \
                            %s\\%s.mp4" %
                            (screen_resolution, image_location, subfolder, count, preset[2], qaulity, duplicated_frame, video_path, video_filename), shell = True)
```

and the error I am getting is:

TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str

I have tried searching for a solution but not getting anywhere fast. I know the %d is looking for an input from the list at the end but from what I can see this is also the way to tell the FFMPEG to use all files in the image location.

Hopefully someone can help with this, apologies if this is a duplicate question but as mentioned, I have tried searching, a lot.

Comment: Is there any reason why you didn't already try replacing `%d` with `%s`?

Comment: I have been using %d as from reading the documentation for ffmpeg this is what is needed to select all files rather than just 1 specified file (at least that is my understanding of it).

Comment: Oh, so you're saying you have to leave the `%d` in there, unparsed by python, so it can get parsed by FFMPEG? Surely there's a way to escape it then, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to manually construct shell strings. Let `subprocess` do that for you.

You can pass an array of command line arguments, and Popen will take care of properly escaping everything:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        "C:/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe",
        "-r", "1",
        "-f", "image2",
        "-s", screen_resolution,
        "-i", os.path.join(path, image_location, subfolder, "%d" + extension),
        "-preset", preset[1],
        "-crf", str(qaulity),
        "-r", str(duplicated_frame),
        "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
        os.path.join(video_path, video_filename)
    ]
)
```

Comment: Brilliant, this pretty much solved my issue, the only change I had to make was this: "-i", os.path.join(path, image_location, subfolder, '%d' + extension). Thanks for your help